# Do Bayesian network inference algorithms assume specific distributions of data?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, bayesian, directed-acyclic-graphs, bayesian-networks

I have some data and I want to learn a Bayesian network for this data and then use this Bayesian network for inference. I use `learn_struct_gs2` from the [Bayes Net Toolbox](https://github.com/bayesnet/bnt) in MATLAB for this purpose. By using `learn_struct_gs2` a Bayesian network is learnt. However, I am wondering:

When we want to learn the Bayesian network from data, should the values of our features follow a specific distribution (e.g., normal distribution, etc.)? and if the values of our features don't follow a distribution we can not use the Bayesian learning?

For example, imagine the values of a feature are:
0, 10,11,18,100, 1250, ...

Can we use Bayesian learning for this?

I am new to Bayesian learning and artificial intelligence and I spent a lot of time to find the answer of this question but I couldn't.

My second question is:
So many learning methods exist, for example Bayesian learning, neural network and so on. How can I find out which of these methods is appropriate for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Simulations, simulations, simulations.**

Generating artificial datasets is what method developers often use and it's a great way for practitioners to verify and codify their assumptions about their data. Computing time is so cheap today that one can often empirically test the appropriateness of an algorithm more readily than parsing through the dense literature and theory.

This is not to say that one should entirely dispense with learning the fundamentals, like what one will learn in advanced undergraduate and graduate-level training (or in free texts like Bishop's "*Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning*"). However, a user that knows how to argue with empirical tests can be extremely convincing and can use them to pole vault over gates that academics tend to erect.

In your case, try making some simple mock networks that generate data using a range of distributions. A null case might be Gaussian distributions; perhaps your extreme case could be log-normal. Then test whether the algorithm infers the correct networks under those different distributions. The key thing is: treat it like a playground and go play. Or if you prefer stodgy similes: treat it like a laboratory and experiment.